# HttpMessageNotReadableException errors on my Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, api, postman

I want to send an object to my database, with spring framework. Here is my code in the controller :

```
    @PostMapping("/createBarangByJson")
public ResponseEntity<?> createBarangByJson(@RequestBody RequestUser body)
{
    Integer cDet = crudService.simpleCreateByJson(body);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(cDet);
}
```

}

I already make setter getter for request class, and here is my code in DaoImpl :

```
    @Override
public Integer simpleCreateByJson(RequestUser reqUser)
{
    String sql = "INSERT INTO public.jualbeli(nama_barang, kuantitas, harga, tanggal, created_by) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    Integer result = jdbcTemplate.update(sql, reqUser.getNama_barang(), Integer.parseInt(reqUser.getKuantitas()), Integer.parseInt(reqUser.getHarga()), reqUser.getTanggal(), reqUser.getCreated_by());
    return result;
}
```

But when I send this data :

```
[
{
    "nama_barang": "buku",
    "kuantitas": "17",
    "harga": "500000",
    "tanggal": "2020-08-01",
    "created_by": "adit"
}
```

]

The error said :

```
"timestamp": 1615207817069,
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException"
```

Anybody knows what's wrong ?

Comment: This would indicate that something is wrong about the way you called your API. I would check the logs on the server. There's likely more information following the "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException" about WHY the message is not readable. I.e. Did you send json? In that case, you'd need to change @PostMapping(path = "/createBarangByJson", consumes="application/json")

Comment: @AlexanderKatsenelenbogen yes I send Json data and I already use @PostMapping("/createBarangByJson") on my controller

Comment: Pradan Note that I changed the arguments to your PostMapping annotation: path = "/createBarangByJson", consumes="application/json"

If you're sending json, you will need that.

Comment: @AlexanderKatsenelenbogen @PostMapping("/createBarangByJson", consumes="application/json") you mean like that ?

Comment: @AlexanderKatsenelenbogen @PostMapping("/createBarangByJson", consumes="application/json") you mean like that ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: But it's syntax error @AlexanderKatsenelenbogen

Comment: @PostMapping(path="/createBarangByJson", consumes="application/json")

Comment: Sorry. I didn't notice that you were missing the "path" key for your "/createBarangByJson"

Comment: Oww, sorry my bad, I already change it but I still got the same error, is it because the invalid Json data that I want to send or what ? @AlexanderKatsenelenbogen

Comment: In that case, we'll need more information about the cause of the exception. Could you check the logs and post the full exception message here?

Comment: the log on my postman or ? @AlexanderKatsenelenbogen

Comment: No -> the logs in your spring application

Comment: oww, here : 
Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of com.example.demo.beans.RequestUser out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6d6db6b1; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.example.demo.beans.RequestUser out of START_ARRAY token
@AlexanderKatsenelenbogen

Comment: Okay. i understand now. You are sending a JSON array.

```
[{
    "nama_barang": "buku",
    "kuantitas": "17",
    "harga": "500000",
    "tanggal": "2020-08-01",
    "created_by": "adit"
}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending a JSON array:

```
[{
    "nama_barang": "buku",
    "kuantitas": "17",
    "harga": "500000",
    "tanggal": "2020-08-01",
    "created_by": "adit"
}]
```

You need to send

```
{
    "nama_barang": "buku",
    "kuantitas": "17",
    "harga": "500000",
    "tanggal": "2020-08-01",
    "created_by": "adit"
}
```

Also you should require

```
@PostMapping(path="/createBarangByJson", consumes="application/json")
```

instead of

```
@PostMapping("/createBarangByJson")
```